# Android Hilt proguard-rules obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard, dagger-hilt

I've applied android Hilt to my project and everything works fine in debug mode.

The issue here is when I set minifyEnabled to true in release mode, app crashed.
This is because my app package directories are obfuscated and Hilt can 't find proper classes at runtime.

If I set minifyEnabled to false, app works fine but all the classes in package directories can be shown in decompiling tools.

How do I obfuscate my source code while using android Hilt?

Guide me please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the Proguard rules for all the libraries you are using so that you can successfully obfuscate the code and have it all work correctly